# Programmatically modify user quota

Tags: linux, centos, scripting, quota

I have already configured my server to work with user quotas and everything works well. I can modify user quota with the `edquota` command.

How can I do this programmatically, from a bash script for example?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`setquota`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/setquota.8.html).

In the simple form the command is

```
setquota user blockquota blocklimit inodequota inodelimit filesystem
```

E.g.

```
setquota foo 10G 10G 0 0 /data
```

to set both the soft quota and hard limit to 10 GB and no inode limit for user `foo` on `/data`.

I suppose you could use `quota -u $username` to get the current quotas, but I'm not sure how easy that is to parse with a script.